# Get certain value in the string from text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this in my text file:

---

```
000000000:Carrots:$1.99:214:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000001:Bananas:$1.99:872:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000002:Chocolate:$2.99:083:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$1.99
000000003:Spaghetti:$3.99:376:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$2.99
000000004:Tomato Sauce:$1.99:437:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000005:Lettuce:$0.99:279:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000006:Orange Juice:$2.99:398:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$1.99
000000007:Potatoes:$2.99:792:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$1.99
000000008:Celery:$0.99:973:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000009:Onions:$1.99:763:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000010:Chicken:$8.99:345:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$7.99
```

---

000000010:Chicken:$8.99:**345**:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$7.99

I need to get the value of each of the "quantity" values from the position in bold.

EDIT:
I want to also compare the values that I got and give an error if the quantity is low.

Comment: split it by a common delimiter and then reference the column you want

Comment: this data looks like Colon separated so just split on newline and colon

Comment: @MikeT I have, I just don't know how to get the specific value

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Can you explain how I would do that?

Comment: @kolton Edit your post and include the code you've tried so far, so we know where to start with helping.

Comment: [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not at the computer anymore. I'll let everyone know what works when I get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with minimal memory consumption in case of large input data.
In additional: there are not processing of incorrect data in quantity column. To do this just replace **int.Parse** block;

This is several methods to process file data using LINQ expressions

```
    internal static class MyExtensions
{
    /// <exception cref="OutOfMemoryException">There is insufficient memory to allocate a buffer for the returned string. </exception>
    /// <exception cref="IOException">An I/O error occurs. </exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"><paramref name="stream" /> does not support reading. </exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="stream" /> is null. </exception>
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(this Stream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            do
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null) break;
                yield return line;
            } while (true);
        }
    }

    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="line"/> is <see langword="null" />.</exception>
    public static IEnumerable<string> ChunkLine(this string line)
    {
        if (line == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("line");
        return line.Split(':');
    }

    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="chuckedData"/> is <see langword="null" />.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Index should be not negative value</exception>
    public static string GetColumnData(this IEnumerable<string> chuckedData, int columnIndex)
    {
        if (chuckedData == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("chuckedData");
        if (columnIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Column index should be >= 0", "columnIndex");
        return chuckedData.Skip(columnIndex).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is example of usage:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var values = EnumerateQuantityValues("largefile.txt");
        // do whatever you need
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> EnumerateQuantityValues(string fileName)
    {
        const int columnIndex = 3;
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            IEnumerable<int> enumerable = stream
                .EnumerateLines()
                .Select(x => x.ChunkLine().GetColumnData(columnIndex))
                .Select(int.Parse);

            foreach (var value in enumerable)
            {
                yield return value;
            }                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just consider if you are managed to get all these lines in string array or list.

you can apply the below code to get the collection of quantity as `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
var quantity = arr.Select(c =>
{
    var temp = c.Split('$');
    if (temp.Length > 1)
    {
        temp = temp[1].Split(':');
        if (temp.Length > 1)
        {
            return temp[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}).Where(c => c != null);
```

**UPDATE**

Check the Fiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/HqKdeI

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to split the string

```
string data = @"000000000:Carrots:$1.99:214:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000001:Bananas:$1.99:872:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000002:Chocolate:$2.99:083:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$1.99
000000003:Spaghetti:$3.99:376:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$2.99
000000004:Tomato Sauce:$1.99:437:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000005:Lettuce:$0.99:279:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000006:Orange Juice:$2.99:398:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$1.99
000000007:Potatoes:$2.99:792:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$1.99
000000008:Celery:$0.99:973:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000009:Onions:$1.99:763:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$0.99
000000010:Chicken:$8.99:345:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$7.99";

string[] rows = data.split(Environment.Newline.ToCharArray());

foreach(var row in rows)
{
    string[] cols = row.Split(':');
    var quantity = cols[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this.

```
// Read all lines into an array
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\path\to\your\file.txt");

// Loop through each one
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Split into an array based on the : symbol
    string[] split = line.Split(':');

    // Get the column based on index
    Console.WriteLine(split[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example code below. The string you care about is named theValueYouWantInTheString.

```
char[] delimiterChar = { ':' };
string input = @"000000010:Chicken:$8.99:345:03/11/2015:03/11/2016:$7.99";
string[] values = input.Split(delimiterChar);
string theValueYouWantInTheString = values[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem, use regular expression. Now you have two problems.

Here is a program that uses your input as a txt file. The function GetQuantity returns a list with int that contains the quantity. With this approach you can define more groups to extract information from each line.

```
namespace RegExptester
{
    class Program
    {

        private static List<int> GetQuantity(string txtFile)
        {
            string tempLineValue;
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]*:[a-zA-Z]*:\$[0-9]*\.[0-9]*:([0-9]*).*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            List<int> retValue = new List<int>();
            using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(txtFile))
            {
                while (null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    Match match = regex.Match(tempLineValue);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                       if(match.Groups.Count == 2)
                       {
                           int numberValue;
                           if (int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out numberValue))
                               retValue.Add(numberValue);
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            return retValue;
        } 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tmp = GetQuantity("c:\\tmp\\junk.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently from each line you want the part between the 3th and the 4th colon. Linq can do that for you:

```
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    // read all text and divide into lines:
    var allText = textReader.ReadToEnd();
    var allLines = textReader.Split(new char[] {'\r','\n'}, StringSplitIoptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     // split each line based on ':', and take the fourth element
     var myValues = allLines.Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {':'})
         .Skip(3)
         .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you want less readability, of course you can concatenate these statements into one line.